# attaching picture to mail blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have saved an image in the device memory after taking a picture from the camera. I want to send this image as an email attachment. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How To - Create and send messages
Last Updated: 26 May 2009
Article Number: DB-00433
[link](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800698/How_To_-_Create_and_send_messages.html?nodeid=1008283&vernum=0)

How To - Create an attachment
Last Updated: 19 April 2006
Article Number: DB-00009
[link](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/796557/800332/800698/How_To_-_Create_An_Attachment.html?nodeid=800544)

Comment: Thanks for the links... I have sorted out the method... but when i try attach pics i get a dialog "Email service does not support these types of attachments. Change the Send using field or remove the attachments"... and i even cant get Send option. I m running JDE 5.0 on 8520 simulator...

Comment: ESS and MDS Simulators have limited support for attachments. http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sending-Attachment-From-Java-Application-Problem/m-p/162207#M19425. have you tried to reproduce this issue on a real device?